# Validation (CSS 3.0): "important" is not a valid value (VS 2012)

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, less

I'm using less file to define styles in my Web Application.
Unfortunately, every time I use the "important" declaration in Visual Studio 2012, for example:

```
color: #FFFFFF !important;
```

i get the following Warning:

```
Validation (CSS 3.0): "important" is not a valid value for the .... property.
```

But the "!important" declaration is working properly and I need to use it.
What I am doing wrong? Are there some wrong setting in VS options? I'm also using "Web Essentials 2012" extensions for VS 2012.

Comment: Who cares what some IDE says, test the validation on http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/. Also try not to use !important where possible, re-order the CSS to make better use of the cascade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. I haven't tried VS2012, but the HTML5/CSS3 validator in VS2010 was not to be trusted – I can't remember if this was a MS or third-party add-in, but I remember the developer admitting that this was only experimental.

I notice that you correctly write `!important` but that your error log writes `important` (without the exclamation point). Could it be that VS2012 for some odd reason skips those? You should consider [filing a bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

`!important` is certainly valid, but should be avoided in any case, as it's hard to override. Therefore, some validators will give you a warning due to them being bad practice. Practising a slightly higher specificity to override styles will save you a lot of headache.

TL;DR:
Simply ignore the error and keep rocking on.

Comment: It even calls it "CSS 3.0" — who are we kidding?